# Sharing TeamCity between two distinct teams

Tags: teamcity

Our team has a full licence for the TeamCity server, as well as 7 additional agents. Another unrelated team has reached the limits of their free TeamCity licence and is eyeing our licences up.

The powers that be think it's a good idea to run both teams using the same enterprise licence, which means that we'd be hosting the TeamCity configurations on the same server, and either sharing agents or somehow assigning some agents to one team, some to another.

One concern I have is that configuring an agent to only accept certain builds is difficult - our team has hundreds of build configurations, and we create new ones all the time. To limit an agent to certain builds, you have to fully specify the whitelist. So maintaining the agents such that we have full use of some agents, and the other team has full use of theirs will be a pain. On the other hand, just using one pool of agents means now you have arguments over priority and starvation, etc.

Does anyone have any experience of this? Is it a workable solution? How do you configure agents to reserve them for a particular team? How do you configure the server so that each team only sees their own projects, build configurations and agents? Basically what we'd want is complete separation of the projects, just using the same TeamCity server and agents.

As a gut feeling it doesn't look like a good idea...

edit: As an aside, does Hudson do this better? The ivory tower architects want us to change from TeamCity to Hudson because other people are using Hudson. If I tell them this sharing TeamCity won't work, the Hudson camp will probably use it as a stick to beat us with. Joy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what version of TeamCity you're using but the newly released TeamCity v7.0 now has a new Agent Pool feature that provides a much easier way to distribute agents. It may be of interested to you, check out the [What's New section](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/whatsnew/index.html) or the [Agent Pools docs](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/Agent+Pools) for more info.

I had a similar issue with our two departments starting to share the same TeamCity instance to save the expenses of additional licenses. I must admit we didn't really have any issues apart from our agents were now twice as busy.

I enabled *Per-project permissions* on the Global Settings page and created 2 user groups, one for 'us', and the other for 'them'. You can then configure each group's roles accordingly. If a group does not have the Project Viewer role for a project then it does not appear for them - a great way to only display necessary projects to the group; but there are plenty of other role options to use.

I have never used Hudson so can't compare unfortunately. I should really try it out but as I've always got on so well with TC I've never had a reason too.

Comment: The Agent Pools feature does sound good. We're on 6.5 unfortunately, but upgrading could be an option. What granularity do you have for assigning builds/projects to pools? We'd want to do it at as high a level as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can make builds on run on certain agent, from the build configuration of each build in the agent requirements section, thereby limiting any build configuration to certain agents.
For example if your agent for one team is teamcity1 you can specify:

```
system.agent.name  does not equal teamcity1
```

So it will never run on that agent.
That way you can at least copy build configurations and they will run on seperate agents without the fiddle agent configuration.

Comment: Yeah, the problem with this approach is that it's opt-out instead of opt-in. I want a solution we put in place once and it keeps the two teams separated without needing future work when one team creates a new configuration and forgets to put this requirement in. I'm trying to avoid a situation where we are constantly having to do gardening to keep our TC configuration clean.Given the fact that we currently have the setup to ourselves, it would have to work such that doing this isn't an ongoing cost to us.

Answer (score 1):

The other team can create a new Teamcity server, and it will have its own new set of free build configurations and agents.

Comment: This is what they have at the moment, but they've hit the limits of the free licence and need more projects and more build agents. Hence they are now eyeing up our licences. I want them to buy their own, the management want them to use ours. If it can work without costing my team time in maintenance, I'll consider it. But it doesn't look like TeamCity is designed for one server to support two completely distinct teams. I guess it would be called TeamsCity then.

Comment: Have them create additional servers. Jetbrains has said they do not have any issues with this.

Answer (score 1):

We don't do this any more, but we used to split our agents into pseudo-pools so we could reserve some for compilations and others for automated tests (because automated test jobs can swamp the grid).  We added a "can_run_tests" property to the test agents, and made those builds require that property as an agent condition.  It worked great, and it's the sort of thing you can bake into the AMI for a set of cloud agents.

What we do now is to make the compilation and test builds require on different AMIs, which does essentially the same thing.